# Web Access and broadcast issues for HP Switch V1810-48G, PK.1.40

Tags: networking, switch, hpe

I have some trouble with an HP Switch: HP V1810-48G PK.1.40
After few days after the reboot, its LAN webinterface becomes unaccessible, its IP address not pingable anymore and it starts to block some broadcast packets (like DHCP requests) in connected ports. All not-broadcast traffic is well managed between ports.

The problem goes away with a reboot, but after few days it will happen again.
I check the firmware version and seems to be the last one.

Do you have any suggestion except chaning the switch?

Comment: Sounds like  bad switch hardware or firmware to me

Comment: That's a J9660A? Latest firmware is PK1.37 from May: https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9660A&lang=&cc=&prodSeriesId= Apart from that, factory reset and reconfigure.